# RAID1 to store ~10 million files <3MB?

Tags: raid1

I have many small files in all of my websites, which are backed up every day to local computer. Today I use external 2TB HDD, but due to lack of free space wanna buy additional HDD. So my goal is not just to increase capacity, but also provide additional protection. What about getting 8TB (2x4TB) RAID1 array? Is it worth it? I think 2 are better than 1.

Comment: Yes, RAID is a good thing and in general it is worth it. However there is a lot more to good backups then redundant hard drives. If you are serious, you should learn more about it.

Comment: What about it?  Yes, 2 copies of data is better than 1.

Comment: Just a thought, if you are running on Linux, but you might want to consider using ZFS with mirroring.  Using snapshots and zfs send/recv will backup those small files much faster then any filesystem backup tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RAID1 is good. RAID10 is better, but RAID10 might not be needed in your use case, if you don't need speed as well as redundancy.

Don't forget the 3, 2, 1 rule in backups.
3 copies minimum
2 of those copies on separate devices
1 copy off-site

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't know 3-2-1 rule as a theory, but practically also have 3 copies on separate devices. :)